# Use the relative velocity formula to find $v_{2f}$ in terms of $v_{1f}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

> **Q:**
> A $0.150\text{ kg}$ glider is moving to the right ($+x$) on a frictionless, horizontal air track with a speed of $0.80\text{ m/s}$.  It has an elastic collision with a $0.300\text{ kg}$ glider moving to the left ($-x$) with a speed of $2.20\text{ m/s}$.
>
> **a.)** What is the initial momentum of each glider?  Express the momentum in terms of unit vectors.
>
> **b.)** Use the relative velocity formula to find $v_{2f}$ in terms of $v_{1f}$.
>
> **c.)** Use the relative velocity result to solve conservation of momentum to find the velocity (magnitude and direction) of each glider after the collision.

I've figured part (a) using the definition of momentum: $p=mv$:

**1st glider**: $$p_1 = m_1 v_1 = (0.15\text{ kg})(+0.8\hat{x}\text{ m/s}) = +0.12\hat{x}\text{ kg m/s}$$

**2nd glider**: $$p_2 = m_2 v_2 = (0.3\text{ kg})(-2.20\hat{x}\text{ m/s}) = -0.66\hat{x}\text{ kg m/s}$$

Parts (b) and (c) are what have me confused at the moment. I'm not positive I have the equations for relative velocity right nor how to solve for $v_{2f}$ in terms of $v_{1f}$. My book lists this an equation that can be gotten from manipulation of a kinetic energy equation: $v_{1i} – v_{2i} = -(v_{1f} - v_{2f})$. Is this the relative velocity formula? would just isolating $v_{2f}$ in this equation be solving for $v_{2f}$ in terms of $v_{1f}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no clue whatsoever as to what the "relative velocity formula" is, but I think that the idea here is to find a relation between the $v_i^f$ (assuming $f$ means final).

That comes straight out of momentum conservation (using $s$ for starting and $f$ for final and that the problem is in one dimension): $$ p^f = p^s \implies m_1 v_1^f + m_2 v_2^f = m_1 v_1^s + m_2 v_2^s $$ which has only two unknowns, namely the $v_i^f$.

(Kinetic) energy conservation would lead to: $$E^f = E^s \implies m_1 (v_1^f)^2 + m_2 (v_2^f)^2 = m_1 (v_1^s)^2 + m_2 (v_2^s)^2$$ which again has the two *same* unknowns.

So, two equations with two unknowns...

Comment: Do not forget velocities have signs (so, also do momenta).

Comment: Hmm, I am still not seeing how I will find v2f in terms of v1f. My book says v1i – v2i = -(v1f - v2f), along with conservation of momentum, can be used to solve for the two unknowns. I believe I am supposed to end up with these equations for the "relative velocity result": http://imgur.com/uJ9z2

Comment: Am I just missing some algebra we can do with the equations we are currently looking at to get those resultant equations?

Comment: Well @Matt, can you see how v2f comes out of the equation you just pasted in the comment above? I mean, there are 4 symbols in a linear combination, 2 have known values, so the other 2 can be expressed in terms of each other. (This is all b is asking for.)

Comment: How v2f comes out of: v1i – v2i = -(v1f - v2f) or the equation from the imgur link?

Comment: $v_{1i} – v_{2i} = -(v_{1f} - v_{2f})$ $\Leftrightarrow v_{1i} – v_{2i} = -v_{1f} + v_{2f}$ $\Leftrightarrow v_{1i} – v_{2i} + v_{1f} = v_{2f}$ $\Leftrightarrow v_{2f} = v_{1i} – v_{2i} + v_{1f}$. But again, I have no idea how this equation comes about.

Comment: Ah yea, I see that. The thing is, part c uses those equations from the imgur link and since it says "use the relative velocity result" I expected to get them somehow from part b. Is there anyway those imgur equations can be derived from v2f=v1i–v2i+v1f?

Comment: Nope. I am pretty sure that the imgur equations come from massaging the energy and momentum conservation equations.