# Optics problem: Determining the new focal length when changing from film to CCD detector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses

> An older camera has a lens with a focal length of 50mm and uses
>   34-mm-wide film to record its images. Using this camera, a
>   photographer takes a picture of the Golden Gate Bridge that completely
>   spans the width of the film. Now he wants to take a picture of the
>   bridge using his digital camera with its 12-mm-wide CCD detector. What
>   focal length should this camera's lens have for the image of the
>   bridge to cover the entire detector?

I figured out that I can construct two equations using the lens equation. Each equation corresponds to each case (1) the film and (2) CCD.

Moreover, we need to use  the length-distance relationship in order to express the distance term in the lens equation in terms of the length of the image.

$$
m = \frac{y_o}{y_i}=\frac{d_o}{d_i}
$$

where $y_o$ and $y_i$ are the lengths of the object and the image, and $d_o$ and $d_i$ the distances of the object and the image from the lens.

For the film, we have
$$
\frac{y_o}{34}=\frac{d_o}{d_i} \Rightarrow d_i = \frac{34d_0}{y_0}
$$
and for the CCD
$$
\frac{y_o}{12}=\frac{d_o}{d_i} \Rightarrow d_i = \frac{12d_0}{y_0}
$$

Hence we have the equations
$$
\frac{1}{d_o} + \frac{y_0}{34d_o} = \frac{1}{50}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{d_o} + \frac{y_0}{12d_o} = \frac{1}{f}
$$

I think we can only set up these two equations as far as the problem is concerned. The difficult part is dealing with three variables in just two equations. I wonder if I have set up the lens equation properly or if the equations can be simplified further.

Comment: I believe I did my work on this problem. Do you have any suggestions on improving this question? This example homework question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16182/use-the-relative-velocity-formula-to-find-v2f-in-terms-of-v1f is considered a good one and I don't think I did less than the  person who posted this question.

Comment: First, pulling a question from 4 years ago isn't a good comparison because site policies change over the years. Second, your question is asking us to check your work for you, something that is [considered off topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093). Third, removing the HW question from the linked Q leaves a decent question behind; removing the HW question here leaves nothing behind (in my opinion) which makes it a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key point that you are missing is that the object is very far away compared to all of the other distances.  Combine your final two equations to eliminate $y_0$ and then let $d_0\rightarrow\infty$, i.e. $\tfrac{1}{d_0}\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My equations are valid after all. Is this type of question not allowed on here? I believe I did my work. It's sad that 5 people tagged this as off-topic and I'm in danger of being blocked of asking questions in the future.

Comment: @akino I personally think your question is fine.  As you've pointed out, you didn't post a mindless 'do my work for me' question which is what is truly not allowed here.  Those users probably voted to close the question because it is about a specific problem instead of a 'concept'.  Physics.SE is a big community, and it only takes 5 people to close a question.  Don't be discouraged by it. :)